Find where the product of terms of a geometric progression reaches its maximum

The geometric progression $\{a_n\}$ has first term $a_1 = 1536$ and common ratio $-\tfrac12$. What is the value of $n$ for which the products of the first $n$ terms is maximum?

I really do not understand just how do I even solve this question. This was in my class 9 exam book, one of the only ones I couldn't understand, could you please help me?
There is literally nothing else given other than this.

Well, why not just try?  Write out the first several terms of ${a_n}$.  Does that suggest anything?  Note:  you have to go out a bit further than you might like, but it's not that bad.

If $k>1$, then multiply with $k$ will make your term smaller.

First of all, since we are dealing with a geometric progression and are given the first term as well as the common ratio, we can write the equation for the nth term as $a_n=1536\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}$. From here we can proceed in a number of ways, the easiest is to use basic properties of multiplication.
Note that if $a>0$ then for all $b>1$ we have $ab>a$, that is: multiplying a positive number by a number larger than 1 increases it. Conversely, multiplying by a positive number less than 1 decreases it.
Also, see that multiplying a number by a negative twice yields a positive number again.
Try your problem first with smaller $a_1$, eg. $a_1=10$ and see how it works out.
